# How to set custom header names with ALASQL and XLSX

Tags: angularjs, excel, xlsx, alasql

I'm exporting some tables to excel, using *angular*, *alasql* and *xlsx*. I'm using it as follows:

```
var options = {
    headers: true,
    sheetid: 'users',
    columns: [{
      columnid: 'a',
      title: 'Username'
    }, {
      columnid: 'b',
      title: 'First name'
    }, {
      columnid: 'c',
      title: 'Last name'
    }]
  };

alasql('SELECT * INTO XLSX("test.xlsx", ?) FROM ?', [options, $scope.users]);
```

I was expecting the **columnns** option to customize my table headers. But it ain't doing it.

Any clue why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to customize the headers by using plain SQL:

```
alasql('SELECT firstName AS FirstName INTO XLSX("test.xlsx", ?) FROM ?', [options, $scope.users]);
```

That worked, the header for the firstName would be FirstName.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes you want to use Headers including blank spaces (Separated By) or... using headers that are reserved words (Deleted), in both cases you can use [] like this:

```
alasql('SELECT firstName AS FirstName, [Deleted] AS [Erased], Separated AS [Separated By] INTO XLSX("test.xlsx", ?) FROM ?', [options, $scope.users]);
```